# how to change date format in servlet jsp?

Tags: java

From database, the format will be coming yyyy-MM-dd. Instead would like to display MM-dd-yyyy.

```
public static final String MM_DD_YYYY_DASH = "MM-dd-yyyy";
public static final String YYYY_MM_DD_DASH = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your non-working code.

Comment: Change when it is used *where*?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
public static final String MM_DD_YYYY_DASH = "MM-dd-yyyy";
public static final String YYYY_MM_DD_DASH = "yyyy-MM-dd";

// an example date with format MM-dd-yyyy
String oldDateString = "12/08/2010";
String newDateString;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(YYYY_MM_DD_DASH);
Date d = sdf.parse(oldDateString);

// exactly after here is useful for you
sdf.applyPattern(YYYY_MM_DD_DASH);
newDateString = sdf.format(d);
```